# Python: Logistic regression max_iter parameter is reducing the accuracy

Tags: python, logistic-regression, cross-validation, multiclass-classification

I am doing multiclass/multilabel text classification. I trying to get rid of the "ConvergenceWarning".

When I tuned the **max_iter** from default to **4000**, the warning is disappeared. However, my model accuracy is reduced from **78** to **75**.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


logreg = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
            ('clf', LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, C=1e5, solver='lbfgs',multi_class='ovr' ,random_state=0, class_weight='balanced' )),
           ])
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

print('Logistic Regression Accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))

cv_score = cross_val_score(logreg, train_tfidf, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print("CV Score : Mean : %.7g | Std : %.7g | Min : %.7g | Max : %.7g" % (np.mean(cv_score),np.std(cv_score),np.min(cv_score),np.max(cv_score)))
```

Why my accuracy is reducing when max_iter =4000?
Is there any other way to fix 
*** "ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge. Increase the number of iterations. "of iterations.", ConvergenceWarning)" ***

Answer (score 7):

It's missing the data used in the question so it's not possible to reproduce the problem but just guess.

Some things to check:

1) Many estimators such as `LogisticRegression` likes (not to say requires) scaled data.  Depending on your data, you may want to scale with `MaxAbsScaler`, `MinMaxScaler`, `StandardScaler` or `RobustAScaler`. The optimal choice depends on the kind of problem you are trying to solve, data properties like sparsity, whether negative values are welcomed by the downstream estimator, etc.  Scaling data usually speeds up convergence, that may even not require to increase `max_iter`.

2) In my experience, `solver` not `"liblinear"` requires more `max_iter` iterations to converge given the same input data.

3) I didn't see any 'max_iter`set in your code snippet.  It currently defaults to`100`  (sklearn 0.22).

4) I saw you set the the regularization parameter `C=100000`.  It's drastically reduce the regularization, as C is the inverse of regularization strength.  It's expected to consume more iterations and may lead to overfit the model.

5) I didn't expect that a higher `max_iter` would get you lower accuracy.   The solver is diverging rather than converging.  The data may not be scaled or the random state is not fixed or the tolerance `tol` (defaults 1e-4) became to high.

6) Check you `cross_val_score` cross-validation parameter `cv`.  If I'm not wrong, the default behavior doesn't set the random state which result in variable mean accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I increased the `max_iter` by small increments (from default 100 to 400 first and then intervals of 400) till I got rid of the warning. And, interestingly it increased the model performance parameters (Accuracy, Precision, Recall, F1 Score). Intuitively that makes sense as now the convergence happens and you reach the optimal solution vs. in the earlier case you weren't.